# Which config transform is applied when running in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-config-transform

Which config transform is applied when running in Visual Studio?

We have a web config and a series of config transforms that set the connection string value for Dev/Test/Live environments. These transforms work fine when the site is published.

To avoid confusion, I replaced the default value with `set_in_transform` ala ...

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="LLPG.Connection"
           connectionString="set_in_transform"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

However if we just run the site in Visual Studio, the `set_in_transform` value isn't been set.

Is a config transform actually run when you run in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run using IIS Express, then no transform is applied, the main `web.config` is used. Transforms are applied when you deploy to some IIS (whether is your local IIS or in a server).

It's possible to deploy to local IIS (then transform is applied), and use `attach` to debug it (as long as you keep debug attributes in web.config).